# android wepapp develoment framework (css theme)

Tags: android, css, web-applications, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a webapplication for android, where I want to use phonegap.
Moreover I am looking for a framework that helps designing the website with a style similar to a native android app - e.g. like android 4.0 theme (http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html)

I had a look jquery mobile and jqtouch, which seem to be quite useful for programming purposes but don't come with applicable native-look styles.

Can anyone recommend any sets of (community maintained) css themes?

Answer (score 1):

I know that Rhomobile have made and maintains such themes building on JQuery Mobile/JQtouch for Android, iOS, Blackberry and Windows. You can find them [here](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/tree/master/res/generators/templates/application/public/css). The image-references in the CSS (which is not from JQuery Mobile) can be found [here](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/tree/master/res/generators/templates/application/public/images).
They are intended for Rhomobile's cross-platform framework Rhodes, but should work just as well with phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

[Dojo Mobile](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/mobile) has a nice Android skin, but the js behind that is too big for my tastes

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kendoui.com/ Is the best site I have found on the web to do this.